# App engine Channel API returns no messages

Tags: python, google-app-engine, channel-api

Problem description: channel messages no returned to ajax script.
Initially, messages are delivered to clietn side, but the problem appears when I set larger timeout in js:

> goog.appengine.Socket.POLLING_TIMEOUT_MS = 5000; //poll every 5 seconds

I've added a very basic Python code to test if Channel API works in my Google App Engine app.

```
index:
token = channel.create_channel(CHANNEL_NAME)
channel.send_message(CHANNEL_NAME, message)
#token is passed to template

additional_view:
#is another view, trigger manually from browser after index
from django.utils import simplejson
channel.send_message(CHANNEL_NAME, simplejson.dumps(data))
```

At client side I have a regular js with onMessage code.

The problem is that no messages are returned to client-side requests. They all come empty to polling ajax (as seen in Firebug). In application log I can see that channel is created:

**"Creating channel token channel-2382918168-broadcast with client id broadcast"**
and later message is sent but with a comment:

in between come these requests:

```
INFO     2011-08-03 14:33:32,000 dev_appserver.py:4248] "POST /_ah/channel/connected/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2011-08-03 14:33:33,780 dev_appserver.py:4248] "POST /_ah/channel/disconnected/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

** ....message text...to channel with key (broadcast): no clients connected***

How does channel/message function at deeper level? Are messages lost if no clients are connected or they are retrived by newly connect clients?
If for some reason I create a channel with the same name, would it distroy undelivered  messages it has inside?

Comment: What browsers have you tried adjusting the timeout in?  Have you tried smaller values?  As I recall I've seen this happen in some browsers when using a polling delay 3 seconds or greater.

Comment: I tried FireFox 3.6. Smaller values work. Just wanted to makes less ajax requests, but I guess that is somehow against Channel API rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stay away from setting the `POLLING_TIMEOUT_MS` higher than 1.5 sec, the dev_appserver will assume you have disconnected.

It does not work via polling in production, so you do not have to worry about the timeout really.

**Edit**: just saw Robert's comment; personally I have even had issues if I set the polling to 3sec in Chrome/Safari/Firefox. I now just have `?disable_channel=true` query strings on my apps so that I can run them without setting my laptop on fire with the CPU usage.

Comment: well techincally it *is* polling... but it's [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling), so a timeout between requests doesn't really apply as the connection is kept open until data arrives. This is not possible with the dev-server due to it being single-threaded and so only able to serve one request at a time.

Comment: I often use 1 or 2 second delays without issues.  I also like the idea of just making a disable_channel for when you're not testing working on those features of an app.